# calling a base function on a derived object

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

```
class base{
   public:
   virtual void foo(){
     std::cout << "base::foo was called" << std::endl;;
   }
 
   void bar(){
     foo();
     std::cout << "base::bar was called" << std::endl;;
   }
};

class derived : public base {
  public:
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "derived::foo was called" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
    derived der;
    der.bar();
    // desired output = "base::foo was called" "base::bar was called"
    // actual output = "derived::foo was called" "base::bar was called"

}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? 
Why does the `bar()` function when called on an object of derived class call the `derived::foo` function, even though the function itself only exists in the base class.

Comment: Maybe read about [virtual function specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)

Comment: I assume you are using `public:` in your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a member function in a derived class *overrides* a virtual member function in a base class like this, that means it entirely replaces the function definition for most purposes. So calling the function `foo` on the object `der` created in `main` will usually use the `Derived::foo` definition. This behavior is consistent whether the code calling `foo` is in a member of `Derived`, or a member of `Base`, or neither class.

The two major exceptions are:

1. If you use a "qualified-id" `class_type::func_name` syntax to call the function, that disables the virtual function logic and just calls the function you named (after normal name lookup and overload resolution).

So since you say you want the program to call `base::foo`, change `base::bar` like:

```
void bar() {
    base::foo();
    std::cout << "base::bar was called" << std::endl;
}
```

2. During a constructor or destructor of the base class, the function from the base class (or one of its bases) will be called, ignoring overriders in the derived class(es). The object is considered to not yet or no longer be an object of the derived type. (And if the derived function were called and uses any derived members which are not yet created or already destroyed, this would be trouble.)

Answer (score 1):

`base::foo` is declared `virtual`, hence uses virtual dispatch. If you don't want that then call `base::foo` explicitly:

```
struct  base{
   virtual void foo(){
     std::cout << "base::foo was called" << std::endl;;
   }
 
   void bar(){
     base::foo();
     std::cout << "base::bar was called" << std::endl;;
   }
};
```

(note that all methods are private in your example, I suppose thats just a typo)

Comment: Yes the functions are public, i fixed that in my code exmaple. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You didn't actually answer the actual question, "why". The simple answer is that it's the way it is defined and that makes `virtual` functions useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function `virtual`, the compiler will generate a `vtable` for each object created, and in your case, since the object is a `derived` the function `vtable` will always point to `derived::foo()` for that instance.